#  How to apply class to timeline in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class

I'm working on a little project right now in ActionScript 3. The project is almost finished, but i want to add an intro frame. And then i get a problem.

I have 2 .as file with code. One is called Game, and the another is called intro. Game is the document class.

I have 2 frames and when i start the game, Game class is applied to both of them. So how can i apply Game class to 2nd frame and Intro class to the 1st.

The code is a little bit too long, so wouldn't upload it. Here is some part of it. Also code works perfectly so ai don't have problem with it.

Game.as

```
package  {
      public class Game extends MovieClip {
             public function Game () {
                      //constructor
             }
             // some other functions
       }
 }
```

Intro.as

```
 package  {
      public class Introextends MovieClip {
             public function Intro() {
                      //constructor
             }
             // some other functions
       }
 }
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to play the intro from Game?

Comment: What you say is very unclear and the code doesn't help.

Comment: Create a class called Main and have that control everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot dynamically change the Document Class in AS3, nor would it make any sense from an OOP perspective to be able to. You have three options:

1. Keep the document class as `Game` and have the `Game` class load in `Intro` before it starts the main code.
2. Change the document class to `Intro` and load in the `Game` class after the intro has finished.
3. Create a new class to be a "holder" class, and use that as the document class instead. Then load in `Intro` and `Game` individually.

I would go with Option 3, since it's probably the easiest to implement and it makes the most sense. You can move all the frames from your old main timeline into a new MovieClip, then link that MovieClip to the `Game` class. Make a similar MovieClip for the `Intro` class. Use your new class to create new instances of each at appropriate times programmatically.